# Random Variables, Variance and Coefficients

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, correlation

So, I'm trying to get my head around a question and I was wondering if you could help me.

Given that the correlation coefficient $\rho$ for random variables $X$ and $Y$ is: 
$\;\rho_{\lower{0.5ex}{X,Y}} = \mathsf E[X^\ast\,Y^\ast]$

Where $X^\ast$ and $Y^\ast$ are the standardised versions of random variables $X$ and $Y$ respectively. And given that $a$ is an unknown coefficient

What is the numerical value of $\rho_{\lower{0.5ex}{X,Y}}$ if $X = aY + b$?

Comment: Do you know what does it mean a standardized random variable? That is, do you know what is the relationship between $X$ and $X^*$ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $X=aY+b$ then how are $X^*$ and $Y^*$ related?